# Get instance conditionally in StructureMap

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I have an interface *IFileSystemStructureEvaluator* with two concrete implementations: *NtfsFileSystemStructureEvaluator* and *FtpFileSystemStructureEvaluator*.

I want to be able to request the appropriate *IFileSystemStructureEvaluator* depending on whether the Uri that is passed to the constructor is a file uri of an FTP uri.

How can I achieve this in StructureMap?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check out the [Conditional Object construction post](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2009/01/18/conditional-object-construction-in-structuremap-i-e-fun-with-lambdas.aspx) by Jeremy Miller. It allows you to use some conditional checks in determining what you'll get as an instance. It sounds like a solution to your problem.

http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2009/01/18/conditional-object-construction-in-structuremap-i-e-fun-with-lambdas.aspx

**Edits below**

There have been several questions on the StructureMap users list about doing conditional construction (i.e., return this object if this condition, else this other object).  In order to meet this apparent need, StructureMap 2.5.2 introduces the new ConditionalInstance that allows a user to effectively switch the active Instance based on a Predicate boolean test.  Here's a quick example of using the new Conditional() syntax of InstanceExpression:

```
var container = new Container(x =>
{
    x.InstanceOf<Rule>().Is.Conditional(o =>
    {
        o.If(c => false).ThenIt.Is.OfConcreteType<ARule>();
        o.If(c => true).ThenIt.IsThis(GREEN);
        o.TheDefault.IsThis(RED);
    }).WithName("conditional");
});
```

More available at the wayback machine
https://web.archive.org/web/20090506031557/http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2009/01/18/conditional-object-construction-in-structuremap-i-e-fun-with-lambdas.aspx

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to access constructor arguments. Oh, well.
In any case - thanks for your input.

Comment: This would be helpful if he'd updated his post when he broke the API years later :(